# match numbers from array and display any mismatches from SQL result using PHP

Tags: php, sql

The following code shows results which matches.
I would like to make a small change and make it function like following.

1. if all numbers from the array are matched, it should echo "success"
2. if at least one number is not valid/or no match found, it should echo "no match" and also display the invalid/mismatched numbers.

in short, the entire array should be matched else it should display which array value didn't match.  I tried but couldn't find a proper way.

```
$arr=range(990,997);
$count="5";
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM tbl_numbers_stock 
            WHERE lot_stock > '.$count.' 
            AND lot_number IN (' . implode( ',', $arr ) . ' );';

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<td>" . $row['lot_number'] . "</td>"; echo ", ";
        };

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == count($arr)) {
            echo 'all true';
        } else {
            echo 'some false';
        }

        // Close result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I tried adding

```
$resultt = array_diff($result,$arr);
print_r($resultt);
```

But it showing nothing. SQl table contains only 990,991 and 992. So the `print_r($resultt);` is supposed to display rest of the numbers from 993 to 997, but it does nothing.

Comment: so.. uh, yeah `array_diff($result,$arr);` wont work because `$result` does not contain the actual result, remember that you had to `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` to pull the actual row? you should pull the entire data and put them into an array somewhere.

Comment: It seems to me that you are actually trying to see which stock items within the range specified do not have more than 5 items in stock, is that right? If so you can do that so much easier just using the query, and changing this `WHERE lot_stock <= .$count` or maybe `WHERE lot_stock < .$count`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an additional variable for the matching entries ($lot_number_found), fill it in the while loop
and compare it to $arr:

```
<?php
$arr=range(990,997);
$count="5";
$lot_number_found = array();
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_numbers_stock WHERE lot_stock > '.$count.' AND lot_number IN (' . implode( ',', $arr ) . ' );';

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $lot_number_found[] =  $row['lot_number'];
        };
        $resultt = array_diff($arr, $lot_number_found);
        if(count($resultt) === 0) {
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo 'some false: '.implode( ',', $resultt ) ;
        }

        // Close result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would make that readable